# How to draw an ellipse in GWT?

Tags: gwt, html5-canvas

There is no context2d.ellipse in GWT, so how can I draw an ellipse?  The underlying HTML5 canvas supports it, so I thought I would try and access that using a native method using the following (but it does not work)...

```
ellipse(context.getCanvas(),(double)x,(double)y,50.,80.,0.,0.,Math.PI*2);

...

public final native void ellipse(CanvasElement e, double x, double y, double rx, double ry, double ro, double sa, double ea)
    /*-{
        e.getContext("2d").ellipse(x, y, rx, ry, ro, sa, ea, false);
    }-*/;
```

ideas / solutions?

Comment: What doesn't work about this? Do you get an error in the build, or when you try to call it?

Comment: Throws a TypeError when compiler - that ellipse does not exist

Comment: Sounds like your browser (which browser are you using?) doesn't actually support the ellipse() method - which at least initially is why GWT didn't support it. The answer about emulating ellipse() sounds like a good choice for you (though, I would build it in Java instead of JS, let the compiler work out optimizations as it can).

Comment: using the latest version of chrome & firefox, so doubt thats the issue, further investigation points to something within the wrapping/compiler within GWT.  I was hoping to avoid doing by hand, but it works well.

Comment: If that isn't the issue, then your context object is "wrong" somehow, it is some other object which doesn't have the ellipse function attached to it. Can you share a complete java class that can compile, so we can see the rest of it?

Comment: The context is the standard GWT Context2d returned from a CreateIfSupported call - there is nothing else required to recreate the issue.  I believed that the CanvasElement should be a native element - but when compiled it appears not.  Yes, the object does not have ellipse, but if  I could access the native element, then I believe the JS would work...

Comment: The GWT class Context2d is _just_ the underlying browser object, at least with stock GWT (and no other JS on your page that might change it). That said, there is no reason in your first line to call `context.getCanvas()` - just pass the context directly into JSNI, and the JSNI method then can call ellipse directly on the Context2d instead of calling `getContext("2d")` first. As above though, post a complete example that fails, and we can take a closer look to see what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no implementation you can draw it using lines, just needs a bit of trigonometry...

```js
function drawEllipse(x, y, rx, ry) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
    a = i * Math.PI / 180
    px = rx * Math.sin(a) + x
    py = ry * Math.cos(a) + y
    ctx.lineTo(px, py);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

drawEllipse(100, 100, 90, 30);
drawEllipse(100, 100, 50, 90);
drawEllipse(100, 100, 50, 25);
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=200 height=200></canvas>
```